# Generic constraint based on KClass<T> property to scope down an extension function

Tags: generics, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I am writing a kotlin extension function that should only work for sealed classes. Can I define a [Generic Constraint](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-constraints) - or something similar that serves the same purpose - such that an extension function would only work on classes that are a sealed class?

In my specific example I have an extension function that gets the ordinal of class type within it's sealed class:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> T.sealedClassOrdinal() = T::class.sealedClassOrdinal()

inline fun <reified T : Any> KClass<T>.sealedClassOrdinal() =
    java.superclass?.classes?.indexOfFirst { sub -> sub == this@sealedClassOrdinal.java } ?: -1
```

Right now the first extension function can be called on `Any`. I would like to scope it down to only extend classes that are of sealed type. The property `isSealed` on `KClass<T>` exposes that info, but I don't see how to tell the compiler. I want something like this (pseudo code):

```
inline fun <reified T where T::class.isSealed> T.sealedClassOrdinal() = T::class.sealedClassOrdinal()
```

and/or

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> KClass<T>.sealedClassOrdinal() where this.isSealed =
```

Or any other solution that would achieve such a behavior.